# TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions (I was trying to add/mix BigInt with var)

Tags: javascript, typeerror, bigint

I was trying to add large numbers using BigInt and add to sum.

```
var sum=0; 
    for(let i in ar){
        sum += BigInt(ar[i]);
    }
    return (sum);
```

But got an error saying:

```
sum += BigInt(ar[i]);
               ^

TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and came up to answer that we can not mix BigInt to another types. So I converted integer sum into BigInt and then adding it to BigInt.
as said in "https://javascript.info/bigint":

> alert(1n + 2); // Error: Cannot mix BigInt and other types

> let bigint = 1n;
> let number = 2;

> // number to bigint
> alert(bigint + BigInt(number)); // 3

> // bigint to number
> alert(Number(bigint) + number); // 3
> So my working solution now is:

```
var sum=0
for(let i in ar)
    sum = BigInt(sum) + BigInt(ar[i]);
return (sum);
```